# Why Hadoop uses Kerberos instead of PKI/OAuth for authentication?

Tags: hadoop, kerberos

Why Hadoop prefers Kerberos instead of PKI(Public Key Infrastructure) or oAuth for authentication? What are the design reasons which led to Kerberos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find the below link useful: https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12428537/security-design.pdf

Update: The doc says "...We choose Kerberos over SSL for the following reasons.
1. Better performance Kerberos uses symmetric key operations, which are orders of magnitude faster than public key operations used by SSL.
2. Simpler user management For example, revoking a user can be done by simply deleting the user from the centrally managed Kerberos KDC (key distribution center). Whereas in SSL, a new certificate revocation list has to be generated and propagated to all servers."

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing and after doing some brief research it seems to me that the primary reason for not using OAuth might have been quite trivial - the pdf linked in the previous answer dates back to 2009 whereas OAuth 1.0 was officially released as a standard in late 2010 and OAuth 2.0 which is de facto the standard today was published in late 2012...

Seems there are some misty plans on adding OAuth support to Hadoop: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11744